# What is happening when I use the @func_name.setter annotation and it does not change a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't think my title adequately explains what I'm talking about. Take this code for example:

```
>>> class D:
...     x = None
...     @property
...     def hello(self):
...             return self.x
...     @hello.setter
...     def hello(self, text):
...             self.x = text
... 
>>> d = D()
>>> d.hello = 'hello world'
>>> print d.hello
hello world
>>> print d.x
None
```

For some reason d.hello and d.x do not return the same result. What is happening here?

Comment: are you just trying to set the value of x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D` is an old-style class and therefore doesn't support descriptors: `d.hello = 'hello world'` does not invoke the setter, it just creates an instance attribute which shadows the (useless) descriptor `D.hello`. Inherit from `object`:

```
class D(object):
    ...
```

Comment: That said, the underlying `x` attribute should still be set as an actual instance attribute in `__init__`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Why? I would do that myself, but I can't see any good argument against OP's way, only aesthetic choices. (I do have my doubts about `None` as a default value but that's a different matter.)